# Deducing that $a$ has order $n$ in a group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $a^n = 1$ in a group $G$. Prove that if, for every prime $p$ dividing $n$ we have $a^{n/p}\ne 1$, then $a$ has order $n$.

Comment: What is a_^n-p?

Comment: $a^{n-p}$, I take it.

Comment: $3^{12}=1\pmod{728}, \ 3^{10}\neq1\pmod{728}, \ 3^{9}\neq1\pmod{728}$ and the order of 3 in $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb Z_{728})$ is 6.

Comment: @9959 Considering that the current statement is false, could you verify that $a^{n-p}$ is what you meant originally? I think it is more likely to be $a^{n/p}$ which rings a bell anyway.

Comment: Yes a^n/p is what I meant. I am still trying to learn how to type in the form that you use.

Comment: I had edited it with the correct formatting so that you could learn from it but you wrote over it.  Look at the edit history to see how..

Comment: You can right click on an expression, a menu shows up. Click "show math as" and then "tex commands" to see how we write it. Note that every mathematical expression is enclosed in dollar signs ($).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $r<n$ is the order of $a$. Then $r$ is a divisor of $n$, and there exists a prime $p$ which divides $n/r$. Putting this together, $$a^{n/p}=a^{(rn/r)/p}=a^{rs}=(a^r)^s=1,$$ where $s$ is the integer $n/rp$.

Comment: That is what I tried to show. Thanks for helping me with that.